# Incremental unique identifier in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to set sheet up with an automatically generated unique reference number. The following array formula has worked well in providing a unique number, as well as adding an initial string of text "410-" to the begging when a drop down is triggered in column P, producing an output is similar to "401-00001" etc.

```
=arrayformula( if( len(P2:P), "410-" & text(row(A2:A) - row(C2) + 1, "00000"), iferror(1/0) ) )
```

However, the limitation of the above is that it does not scan the column and continue sequentially from the last used number, it just assigns a number based on the row used. I need the unique reference numbers to be assigned in the order they are activated, which won't necessarily be in a sorted order in the sheet.

How can I adapt this formula to identify the largest number and add one, while keeping the same formatting etc?

(Similar to using a function such as `=ArrayFormula(MAX((A2:A)+1)) )`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The function similar to

`=ArrayFormula(MAX((A2:A)+1)))`

would be

`=arrayformula("410-" & text(max(value(right(A$2:A,5)))+1,"00000"))`

and this would create the next unique identifier.  The problem you have is that you can't use `A$2:A` in the same column as your list of unique IDs as it will create a circular reference and produce an error.

You can use

`A$2:A2` in cells `A3` and fill down but even when you surround this with an if statement, *if column P has a value*, it will still renumber the IDs according to their position on the sheet.

While it is useful to have a formula to generate the ID, the ID needs to be fixed once it has been generated.

You could put the formula that generates the next ID at the top of your sheet and copy and paste values when required.

Maybe use a google script to copy the value automatically onchange in column P